# Solving the Diophantine equation $xy = az + b$ for $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Is there a method to solve Diophantine equations of the form

$$
xy = az + b \tag{1}
$$

where $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$ are unknown and $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ are known constants? There are also bounds on $|x|, |y|, |z|$, call them $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ respectively.

One approach I thought of was rearranging $(1)$ as

$$
xy - az = b \tag {2}
$$

and taking $u = xy, v = z$ to get

$$
1 \cdot u - a \cdot v = b \tag {3}
$$

which can be solved using the Euclidean algorithm and then we find $x, y$ as the divisors of $u$ (both positive and negative), subject to bounds $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll solve the case $\gcd(a,b)=1$ first.

Then for any $x$ with $\gcd(x,a)=1,$ we can solve: $xu+av=1,$ then choose any $y\equiv xub\pmod{ a}.$ Then let $z=\frac{xy-b}{a}.$

We only need to solve for $1\leq x_0<a,$ since we can then choose $x\equiv x_0\pmod a,$ use the same $y$ and the compute $z.$

---

If $\gcd(a,b)=d>1,$ then you have $a=da_0,b=db_0.$

Solve $x_0y_0=a_0z_0+b_0,$ and factor $d=d_1d_2,$ we get a solution:

$$(d_1x_0)(d_2y_0)=az+b.$$

The tricky part of that is factoring $d.$ But that isn't really harder than enumerating all the numbers $<b_0$ which are relatively prime to $b_0.$

---

This should work to find all classes of solutions.

But if you just need one solution, let $d=\gcd(a,b)$, $a_0,b_0$ as before, then let $x=d,y=a_0, z=0.$

Comment: In the second paragraph, shouldn't it read $z = \frac{xy - b}{a}$ in the notation of Eqn. (1) in the question? Looks like you are using the form $xy = bz + a$. If so, that is fine. Just looking for confirmation.

Comment: Yep, got it backwards, Thanks, fixed. @vvg

Answer (score 1):

Equation, $(xy=az+b)$ has parmeteric solution:

Since, $(a,b)$ is given, we take:

$(a,b)=(1,3)$

Hence we have,

$x*y=(1)z+3$

We have the identity:

$(w+1)*(w+11)=(1)(w^2+12w+8)+(3)$

So in the above we take:

$x=w+1$

$y=w+11$

$z=w^2+12w+8$

For, $w=2$ we get:

$(x,y,z)=(3,13,36)$

---